# ArgoCD: Unable to deploy multiple HELM chart in a single application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm trying to deploy different Kafka services using HELM charts in ArgoCD. These charts include Kafka broker, schema registry, KSQLBD, and Kafka UI. I'm trying to install these 4 charts under the same application in ArgoCD. Tried using `DIRECTORY RECURSE: true`. But I'm unable to create the app in ArgoCD.

Getting this error: `Unable to save changes: application spec is invalid: InvalidSpecError: Unable to generate manifests in kafka: rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = Failed to unmarshal "configmap.yaml": failed to unmarshal manifest: json: offset 2: invalid character '{' looking for beginning of object key string`.

**What I have tried**

- Downloaded these charts locally from HELM repositories using the `helm pull <chart-name>` command in 4 different directories
- Pushed the changes in our git repository
- Created a new app in ArgoCD pointing to the root directory
- Set the type to DIRECTORY instead of HELM and checked the DIRECTORY RECURSE
- Tried to CREATE the app (shows the error)
- I've also tried to create individual applications with the different charts (pointing to the actual directories of each of the charts, not the root directory!) and it works fine!

**Note**

Each HELM chart includes template files as well as the values.yaml files.

**My Question**

Is it even possible to deploy different charts in a single application? Or what am I missing?
Is that something related to this answer [link](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4695#issuecomment-718200115)?

Comment: I would think that you could make an umbrella chart that references your 4 helm charts as requirements. Then, in Argo, you would point to your umbrella chart. Issue you may run into is Values collision or manifest collision, where multiple charts reference the same helm value or manifest name

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @lostjon. I've created an umbrella chart that points to my other charts. Then in ArgoCD, I deployed the umbrella chart.